# How do I change counter to `Alph` format of a counter in tcolorbox

Tags: counters, tcolorbox, amsthm

I am trying to implement the idea of a `bigthm` counter---so make the numbering `Alph` format--- in a `tcolorbox` theoremlike environment. With the `amsthm` package, what I needed to do was

```
\newtheorem{bigthm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thebigthm}{\Alph{bigthm}}
```

the same thing doesn't work with a `tcolorbox` theorem: the following two lines

```
\newtcbtheorem{bigtcthm}{Theorem}{}{}
\renewcommand{\thebigtcthm}{\Alph{bigtcthm}}
```

give me the error

```
./bigthm_counter.tex:10: LaTeX Error: \thebigtcthm undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \renewcommand{\thebigtcthm}
                                {\Alph{bigtcthm}}
```

Here is a minimal example comparing the two theoremlike environments, the one from `amsthm` and the other from `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{bigthm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thebigthm}{\Alph{bigthm}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem{bigtcthm}{Theorem}{}{}
\renewcommand{\thebigtcthm}{\Alph{bigtcthm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{bigthm}
  $1=1$
\end{bigthm}

\begin{bigtcthm}{}{}
  $1=1$
\end{bigtcthm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I now see in the `tcolorbox` manual that adding `number format=\Alph` as an option in the bigtcthm environment definition works.